# photo upload using twitcurl on bb10 cascade

Tags: twitter, cascade

I want to add upload photo functionality in twitter using bb10 cascade application. from the forum i come to know that twitcurl is used to integrate twitter on cascade. I check the **twitcurl** page but did not find anything about upload photo(URL: http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/).I want to know how we can upload photo using **twitcurl**.

And i also want to know if i want to upload photo on facebook using bb10 cascade then which api or sdk i have to use.